# JQuery each not working as intended

Tags: jquery

```
    jQuery.get("ajax.php", function(data)
    {
        $(data).find("div[id^='feed']").each(function() //Find every div with id starting with feed in AJAX response
            {
                $('#' + $(this).attr("id")).remove();
            });
        $("#newsfeed").prepend(data);
    });
```

This works for some divs that fit this description in the ajax response, but not all. Thanks in advance.

Just to make it clear, I want to send out an AJAX request for HTML, itterate through all divs in the response. If they share an id with something already in the DOM AND the id starts with 'feed', remove them. Then append the AJAX to the top of newsfeed. Sorry if I didn't properly explain that before.

Comment: You should strive to explain your question better, like what kind of response `data` is, what message you're getting when it's not working, etc., so that ppl won't have to ask you again to understand your problem.

Comment: Why don't you return only necessary data?

Comment: Because I also return any updates to a feed item. If that item exists, I want to remove it and append the new one to the top.

Comment: Data is pure HTML, there is no error, the each function just isn't removing all relevant div tags.

Comment: Regarding your edit, when you say "remove them" do you mean remove them from what was returned from the Ajax, or remove the existing ones from the document (so that they'll then be replaced by what was returned from the Ajax)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with this part:

```
$(data).find("div[id^='feed']")
```

When you pass a string of html to jQuery, like you do with `$(data)`, jQuery creates DOM elements to match the string (these elements are initially detached from the document) and then returns a jQuery object containing *only the top-level elements*. That is, if your string contained nested elements all of the elements get created but only the top-level ones are returned in the jQuery object.

`.find("div[id^='feed']")` then looks for div elements that are *descendants* of the elements in the jQuery object created in the previous step, so it will not match any top-level elements.

The [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) lets you filter the top-level elements, so you could do something like this:

```
jQuery.get("ajax.php", function(data)
{
   var $newEls = $(data);

   $newEls.filter("div[id^='feed']")
          .add( $newEls.find("div[id^='feed']") )
          .each(function() {
       $('#' this.id).remove();
   });

   $("#newsfeed").prepend(data);
});
```

Within the `.each()` you can say `this.id` rather than `$(this).attr("id")`.

Some example html may help clarify what I tried to explain above. Given:

```
data = "<div id='feed1'><div id='feed2'/><div id='xyz'/></div>
        <div id='abc'><div id='feed3'/></div>";
```

(ignoring the line-break which is there only for readability)

Then `$(data)` will create all five divs but return a jQuery object containing only the 'feed1' and 'abc' divs because they are the only top-level ones.

`$(data).find("div[id^='feed']")` returns a jQuery object containing only the 'feed2' and 'feed3' divs, because they are the only descendants of the elements in the `$(data)` jQuery object.

`$(data).filter("div[id^='feed']")` returns a jQuery object containing only the 'feed1' div.

**EDIT:** you could probably simplify it with something like this:

```
jQuery.get("ajax.php", function(data)
{
   $("<div/>").append(data).find("div[id^='feed']").each(function() {
       $('#' this.id).remove();
   })
   $("#newsfeed").prepend(data);
});
```

This creates a completely empty div as a container so that you can use `.find()` within that container and do away with `.filter()`.

Comment: This appears to be working perfectly. It's a bit of a complex hack but is genius. Give me a while for further testing and I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: I've added a simpler method to the end of my answer - lets you use `.find()` without needing `.filter()` or `.add()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't use .find on the jQuery("html snippet") construct. You would have to append it to a container inside your DOM, then remove the unwanted elements. For instance:

```
$('#newsfeed').prepend(data).find('div[id^=feed]').remove();
```

**EDIT**: to remove the items whose IDs start with feed only in the response:

```
$('<div class="moar_feed">' + data + '</div>') // create detached elements from the data response, wrapping them inside a <div with class="moar_feed" (arbitrary class name, not even necessary)
.appendTo('#newsfeed') // add the newly created HTML elements to the #newsfeed. the return value of appendTo is the HTML you just created, so you can now call .find() on it
.find('div[id^=feed]') // find the DIVs with id starting with "feed" inside the newly created elements
.remove() // remove them from the DOM
```

Comment: If `.find()` doesn't work on snippets that would explain the OP's problem, but the code you've posted doesn't achieve the same result as what the OP intends - the original code attempts to remove elements that already exist in the document before appending the new data, where those elements have an id also used in the new data.

Comment: nnnnnn I think you are wrong: the original code is attempting to remove <div> elements from the returned response, hence the $(data).find

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear. I'm attempting to remove data in the DOM that exists in the AJAX response, and then prepend the data in the response to DOM.

Comment: You'll have a hard time manipulating the received data (it's a string) until you append it to the current DOM. That is what my code snippet does.

If you want to avoid a flash of content, you can hide() the elements, and show() them when you're done remove()ing.

Comment: The received data isn't still a string at the point where it is manipulated, because it has been passed to jQuery with `$(data)`, which actually creates elements from the string and returns a jQuery object containing those elements (at that point they are still detached from the document). Regarding what you said in your answer about `.find()` not working, do you have a link to some documentation to back that up? (Because I've successfully used `.find()` on detached elements before.)

Comment: That script removes every element where the id starts with feed. I only want to remove items in the initial DOM where the id starts with feed AND is in the AJAX response.

Comment: I understand. I do not have any documentation to backup my claim, only a test that I did in a blank document:

`$('<div id="findme"/>').find('#findme')`

This test will not return the new DIV, so I concluded that jQuery's .find does not work on detached elements.

If you want to remove only the elements in the response, then you can add `append()` them to a sub-container and execute a `.find()` on that sub-container instead.

Comment: Please see my edited answer for a way to remove the ^feed elements only in your response.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. I'm fairly new to JQuery don't understand your talk of containers. I have edited the initial question, hopefully making it clearer.

Comment: By new container, I just mean "a new div" basically. I will edit my answer again commenting each piece of code so it will be clearer.

Comment: `.find()` does work on detached elements, but (as with attached elements) it looks for _descendants_ of the elements in the jQuery object that you called `.find()` on. That's why it is correct for `$('<div id="findme"/>').find('#findme')` to return an empty jQuery object. See my answer for more details.